# Can't get Carrierwave to work with Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to use Amazon S3 with Carrierwave. This is the first time I use S3 so I am not sure what I am doing most of the time. I am using Carrierwave with Fog, and uploading the files (just images) through ActiveAdmin, but I get a 'broken pipe' error when I try to upload anything

[This](http://pastebin.com/P05skk39) is the full trace of the error.

I set up Carrierwave with this configuration in the initializer:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider                         => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id                => 'myid',
    :aws_secret_access_key            => 'mysecretkey',
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'bucketname'
  config.s3_region = 'EU'
end
```

And I changed this in my uploader class:

```
#storage :file
storage :fog
```

I am using Rails 3.1

Can anyone give me a clue about what's wrong? I've been searching through open issues of Carrierwave and Fog and cant find anything.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I just tried to upload a very small image and it worked, but for some reason >100 KB are giving me the "broken pipe" error.

Answer (score 0):

The s3_region should be `'eu-west-1'`.

Comment: I had that originally and it didnt work... I checked the Amazon docs, and there Ireland is listed as EU: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: I edited my post: the configuration IS working (with EU, I guess thet use both aliases), but it fails with everything over 100 kb or something ridiculous like that

Answer (score 0):

In my case the 'Broken pipe' was being caused by a RequestTimeTooSkewed error.  Here it is explained by the AWS site: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--difference-between-requesttime-currenttime-too-large.html.

So because the default S3 bucket location is the us-east-1 and I'm located in the West I had to change my bucket's "Region" to Oregon or us-west and it worked!